# Outlook 2003 - Emails per minute

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I was wondering if there is a to tell Outlook 2003 only to send x Mails per Minute or something, because right now, when sending to multiple (lots of) recipients, I get:

```
Policy Rejection- Too much mails in timeframe
```

Comment: Please quote the exact error message that you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use fewer recipients at a time. Many email services have limits: per message, per hour or per 24 hour period. Outlook does not have a timer, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

A commercial solution: [Batched Mail component](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/toolbox/batched_mail.html) (single user license €24) :

> At the present moment more and more
>   mail servers impose limitations on the
>   number of outgoing messages sent
>   during a certain period of time. It is
>   done in order to prevent undesirable
>   mass mail distributions. But as well
>   as any other security measures, this
>   restriction brings inconvenience to
>   those users, who send a bulk of mail
>   daily. The use of the Batched Mail
>   allows you to plan the mail sending
>   process. This Microsoft Outlook add-in
>   sends a specific amount of mail during
>   an hour or with a specified delay
>   between sending two messages that go
>   one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set an option to defer the mail to be sent by few minutes. You can find the steps on how to do it here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/use-outlook-rules-to-prevent-oh-no-after-sending-emails/

Don't know if this is what you are expecting.